# Difference between an install EXE and the EXEs found within the install folder

Tags: windows-7, installation, exec

What is the difference between an installation EXE and the EXE files that are found within the installation folder?

**For example:**
The VLC media player install is called "vlc-2.1.3-win64.exe" and is about 24MB.
After installation, you find additional EXE files such as "vlc.exe", "vlc-cache-gen.exe", "uninstall.exe" all under 1MB, inside the installation folder.

Are there any differences between the EXE files before the installation and after installation (except for the size)? Are there any technical differences? Or are all files still normal Executable files with different code in them?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference.  A Windows Installer normally exract data out of compressed dsta files into a speicifc scripted location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way; the people that make VLC create all the files that the program needs in order to operate, and define where the various files need to be for the program to find them.  Included in this are the executable files (EXE files like vlc.exe) that are what you run to use VLC.  They take all the files and combine them together in such a way that they can get the files back out again later.  They then add some more bits to the combined file that your computer uses to work out how to take all those files and put them where they need to be in order for the program to work; this becomes vlc-2.1.3-win64.exe.

In both cases, the executable is still just a series of instructions that the computer follows to accomplish a task.  The installer follows instructions to install VLC.  vlc.exe follows instructions that tell it how to turn a file into a video on your screen.